# ¿Cómo calcular la media y la nota máxima con notas ya almacenadas?

Tags: java

¡¡Hola!! Estoy intentando hacer un programa que lea las notas  de unos alumnos y calcule la media y la nota máxima de ellos. El problema surge, que si fuera pedir datos de notas y almacenarlas yo lo haría de esta manera:

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numAlum, i;
    double suma = 0, media;


    do {
        System.out.print("Número de alumnos de la clase: ");
        numAlum = sc.nextInt();
    } while (numAlum <= 0);


    double[] notas = new double[numAlum]; 


    for (i = 0; i < notas.length; i++) {
        System.out.print("Alumno " + (i + 1) + " Nota final: ");
        notas[i] = sc.nextDouble();
    }


    for (i = 0; i < notas.length; i++) {
        suma = suma + notas[i];
    }


    media = suma / notas.length;


    System.out.printf("Nota media del curso: %.2f %n", media);


    System.out.println("Listado de notas superiores a la media: ");
    for (i = 0; i < notas.length; i++) {
        if (notas[i] > media) {
            System.out.println("Alumno numero " + (i + 1)+ " Nota final: " + notas[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Pero el ejercicio que estoy haciendo, solamente es de 4 alumnos que tienen que estar en el array. ¿Como lo harías? ¿crear 4 arrays por cada alumno almacenando la nota? Muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Después de los comentarios, he entendido mejor tu problema. En la [primera solución](https://es.stackoverflow.com/revisions/31058/1) había entendido que querías almacenar para cada usuario un número determinado de notas. Teniendo en cuenta que me has dicho que ya tienes 4 arrays con notas y que lo único que quieres es sacar la mayor de todas las notas y la media de todas, voy a poner unos valores por defecto para cada array:

```
double[] notas1 = {5.6, 7.8, 9.9, 4.5, 2.5};
double[] notas2 = {8.5, 4.6, 9.7, 4.3, 1.5};
double[] notas3 = {5.6, 8.8, 7.1, 10, 2.5};
double[] notas4 = {6.5, 7.2, 7.3, 7.5, 6.5};
```

Una vez hecho esto, vamos a crear la variable suma y una variable para guardar el valor máximo:

```
double suma = 0.0; //La inicializamos para poder sumarla después
double notaMaxima = 0.0; //La inicializamos a cero porque seguro que va a ser superada, o al menos, es la peor nota que pueden sacar
```

Como todos los arrays tienen la misma longitud podemos coger la longitud del primero y hacer un bucle `for`.

```
for(int i = 0; i < notas1.length; i++){
   suma += notas1[i] + notas2[i] + notas3[i] + notas4[i];
   //Es lo mismo que suma = suma + notas1[i] + notas2[i] + notas3[i] + notas4[i];

   if(notas1[i] > notaMaxima){
       notaMaxima = notas1[i];
   }

   if(notas2[i] > notaMaxima){
       notaMaxima = notas2[i];
   }

   if(notas3[i] > notaMaxima){
       notaMaxima = notas3[i];
   }

   if(notas4[i] > notaMaxima){
       notaMaxima = notas4[i];
   }
}
```

Una vez hecho esto, ya podemos calcular los valores de la media y sacar la nota máxima:

```
double media = suma / (notas1.length * 4);
System.out.println("La media de todas las notas es " + media);

System.out.println("La nota máxima de todas las notas es " + notaMaxima);
```

Comment: A lo que me referia es que solamente se tiene que mostrar 5 notas almacenadas  en un array, mostrar el valor maximo. Pero no hay que pedir ningun dato por teclado. Seguramente me haya explicado mal. Gracias!!

Comment: @bpico ¿Te refieres a que haya varias notas en un array y mostrar la máxima nota de todas?

Comment: exacto, me referia a  arrays ya declaradas ( 4 en total) y mostrar el maximo valor

Comment: @bpico A ver si me entero. Tienes cuatro arrays con, digamos, 5 notas cada uno y quieres que saque el valor máximo almacenado en cualquiera de los cuatro, ¿no?

Comment: Si, el valor maximo y la media. He puesto el ejemplo anterior (es por teclado). El problema que tengo, que no se como sacarlos de la array y hacer las mismas operaciones que he hecho en el ejemplo que he puesto.

Comment: @bpico Vale, ahora edito la respuesta con una posible solución de cómo podrías hacerlo.

Comment: Muchas gracias!! perdona las molestias :)

Comment: @bpico Ya he editado la respuesta. Espero que esta vez sea lo que buscas :)

Comment: Muchas gracias!! me refería a esto :)

Comment: @bpico Me alegro :) Por favor, marca la respuesta como aceptada si te ha resuelto tu pregunta ya que de esta manera futuros usuarios podrán ver de una manera mucho más clara la solución a tu problema. Para ello, tienes un tick a la izquierda de la respuesta (se pondrá en verde). Marcalo y listo :) Gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Para inicializar un array con valores predefinidos tienes que poner dichos valores entre llaves:
    double[] notas={6, 5, 8, 7, 10};